# Is there a flag corresponding to x/X, but for s with chmod on Linux?

Tags: linux, chmod

When using `chmod` (in my case part of `coreutils` 8.12), and recursively setting the `x` bit, there exists the convenient `X` (uppercase letter x), to set the bit only on directories. So if you wanted to remove the `x` from all files and only leave it on folders you could squeeze that into a single invocation like this:

```
chmod -R a-x,a+X /path/to/folder
```

That's especially useful if you work with someone whose conception of unixoid systems originates in the 1980s and octal `755` is all they know.

However, I have not found such a thing for the `s` bit, despite the fact that a similar duality in the meaning of the bit exists on files versus folders. I'm referring to [`chmod(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod), in particular the `setgid` behavior. So if I do:

```
chmod -R g+ws /path/to/folder
```

I end up with files *and* folders alike having the bit set, when all I want is to set it on folders so that files created there are always owned by the owning group automagically.

Is there a convenient way, short of:

```
find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

???

Comment: A small comment: using `X` not only sets the `x` bit for directories but also for regular files to which at least one user has execute access. See `man chmod`.

Comment: @JosephR.: good point. Probably never noticed, because I am using the whole `z-x,z+X` a lot, where `z` is `u`, `g`, `o` or `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `-R` switch to `chmod`, you're saying that you want to apply the permissions change in question to files and folder recursively.

There is no way to tell `chmod` to only apply these settings to one or the other, so you're only recourse is to enlist the assistance of a tool such as `find` to construct the list of directories, and then `exec` the `chmod` command selectively against this list.

You can make this more efficient by calling `chmod` via the `exec` by calling it like so, using the `+` variant of the `exec` command:

```
$ find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

Comment: Thanks in particular for pointing to the `+` variant. There are so many variations of all the different commands, one can hardly keep track of them. This "lesson" has taught me that `+` is worth remembering.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - plus is equivalent to doing it your self using `xargs`. Not all versions of `find` support it, so it's good to keep the `\;` method and the `xargs` method in the back of your mind if you move across different Unixes.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - not completely scientific test but shows some of the differences b/w the options: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2009/05/find-exec-vs-xargs.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this with `chmod` alone. In zsh you can take advantage of recursive globbing and glob qualifiers:

```
chmod g+ws /path/to/folder/**/*(/)
```

In ksh, you can do this, but it will also operate on symbolic links to directories.

```
set -o globstar
chmod g+ws /path/to/folder/**/*/
```

In bash, you can do this, but it will also traverse symbolic links to directories during the recursive descent.

```
shopt -s globstar
chmod g+ws /path/to/folder/**/*/
```

Instead of using the setgid bit on directories, you can use a default ACL on the directories to make files writable by a group.

```
setfacl -d -m g:somegroup:rwx /path/to/folder/**/*(/)
setfacl -m g:somegroup:rwx /path/to/folder/**/*(/)
```

Comment: Not bad, ACLs seem to be closer to what one is used to from admining on Windows than I thought, after all :)